# Trying to print part of an array and replace another string in the same array in Perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and am trying to write a script to do the following.

I have an array, basically its an output of a command.

```
BIP: Message flow 'Message Flow name' on execution group 'EG' is running.(There are bunch of similar lines)
```

So I am using `foreach $_(@array name)` to read each line.

Now I just want the Message Flow name from the array and want to change running to started. and get that in the OP too.
So, I want to get:

```
Message Flow Name,started as my OP.
```

Can you please help?
I tried `splice`, `split` but no use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about some of `your code` that has failed, some `sample input` and `sample desired output`?

Comment: try regex instead of splice and split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @messages = ("BIP: Message flow 'Name1' on execution group 'EG' is running", "BIP: Message flow 'Name2' on execution group 'EG' is running");
for (@messages) {
    if (/BIP: Message flow '(.*?)' .* running/) {
        print("$1 started as my OP\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a ton for the immediate help.